# What is a good technique to separate out latest reply in an email thread?

Tags: python, email

For a project I'm working on, I need to be able to distinguish the latest message in an email thread from the replies below it. For example, if I write "Hello!" to "joeshmo@gmail.com" from "me@gmail.com" and then Joe Shmo replies "What's up?" the email from Joe Shmo to me will look like this:

```
What's up?

On Aug 4, 2014, at 12:09 PM, FirstName LastName <me@gmail.com> wrote:

> Hello!
```

I only want the part that says "What's up?". Is there a library out there that can do this? Gmail does it really well, so clearly it's possible to do right. I'm using python, so I'd prefer a python library.

Comment: Yes, you want the `whats_up_extractor` module.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you provide a link? I googled "whats_up_extractor module" and got nothing.

Comment: In all seriousness, library recommendations are not on-topic here. There are many resources for text processing in Python available, in the standard library and elsewhere.